# T0 vs S0 in inittab for serial ttyS0 access

Tags: serial, inittab

I can't find any documentation on what the difference between "S0" and "T0" in the inittab file for granting serial access to console is. People seem to use it interchangeably:

```
T0:12345:respawn:/sbin/getty -L ttyS0 115200 vt100
```

vs.

```
S0:12345:respawn:/sbin/getty -L ttyS0 115200 vt100
```

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first field was an arbitrary identifier of 1-4 characters. It can be pretty much anything. Its value is treated as an opaque blob by the machine; it's only relevant to human readers.

In ancient versions of Linux and older Unixes, this field was limited to 2 characters.